# while using multiple webpack configration it throws Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

OS ubuntu :20.04
Node version : 10.19.0
Npm version : 6.13.4

Webpack is watching the files…

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[61869:0x3bd1f40]    70396 ms: Scavenge 1376.0 (1408.9) -> 1375.5 (1409.4) MB, 2.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.113, current mu = 0.031) allocation failure 
[61869:0x3bd1f40]    70403 ms: Scavenge 1376.3 (1409.4) -> 1376.0 (1409.4) MB, 2.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.113, current mu = 0.031) allocation failure 
[61869:0x3bd1f40]    70409 ms: Scavenge 1376.7 (1409.4) -> 1376.1 (1409.4) MB, 1.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.113, current mu = 0.031) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1cc2e85be1d]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0x1cc2e84b476]
Security context: 0x292c6829e6e9 <JSObject>
    2: replace [0x292c682905e9](this=0x324e2654f9c1 <Very long string[2361875]>,0x295d21844be9 <JSRegExp <String[44]: [\\\b\f\n\r\v\t\x22\x27\u2028\u2029\0\ufeff]>>,0x295d21844c21 <JSFunction (sfi = 0x26176cf315d1)>)
    3: make_string(aka make_string) [0x21aba38a2ff9] [0x31ffe51826f1 <undefined>:4027] [bytecode=0x26176cf3...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x8fa090 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8fa0dc  [node]
 3: 0xb0052e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb00764 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xef4c72  [node]
 6: 0xef4d78 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [node]
 7: 0xf00e52 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xf01784 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xf043f1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xecd4e6 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
11: 0xecdd6a v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Heap::RootListIndex, int, v8::internal::Object*, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
12: 0xece2f7 v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithHoles(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
13: 0x11a4a4c  [node]
14: 0x11a6bf9 v8::internal::Runtime_RegExpExecMultiple(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
15: 0x1cc2e85be1d 
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 watch: `webpack -d --watch`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

my webpack configration looks like :

```
let config_one={some code}
let config_two={some code}

module.exports=[config_one,config_two]
```

Comment: Are you out of memory?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Yes, out of memory  when I run webpack -d --watch in package.json and after I remove -d it will working fine I want to know why it is giving error while when i use  webpack -d --watch